# How to use hooks in function with return object

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use theme toggle with darkmode and lightmode by using react-redux.

#### Color.js

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const darkMode = {
        primary: 'black',
        secondary: 'white',
}

const lightMode = {
        primary: 'white',
        secondary: 'black',
}

function ColorMode(){
    const mode  = useSelector(state => state.getDarkMode.darkMode);   // Calling from redux saga
    return mode ? darkMode : lightMode
}
```

#### App.js

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Color from 'Color';

const App = () => {
   console.log('Here it is working...', Color.primary) // black
   return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: Color.primary}} /> // Here not working 
         <Text style={{color: Color.secondary}} />  // Here not working
      </View>
   )
}
```

Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

Comment: Rename `ColorMode` to `useColorMode`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [react document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions):

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.

You are using `useSelector` hook in `ColorMode` function which is neither a function component nor is used as a custom hook.

In order to use it as a custom hook, you can change the `App.js` like this:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import useColor from 'Color';

const App = () => {
   const { primary , secondary } = useColor();

   return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: primary}} />
         <Text style={{color: secondary}} />
      </View>
   )
}
```